# deserialize wordpress custom field in json api plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress

In my wordpress theme there is a custom post type named songs and in that post type there is a custom field named playlist which contain songs information like artist name,download link,song lyric etc...

My problem is that this custom field is serialized in json version of my website 
and i don't know how to fix that.

I use [json api plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) for word press.

here is an example of what it shows in json

```
...
"custom_fields": {
    ...
    "playlist": [
      "a:1:{i:0;a:19:{s:5:\"title\";s:44:\"Hosein Tohi And Sami Beigi - Ba Man Miraghsi\";s:3:\"mp3\";s:134:\"http:\/\/dl.paradi3emusic.com\/Musics\/Aban%2094\/Persian\/Single\/Hosein%20Tohi%20And%20Sami%20Beigi%20-%20Ba%20Man%20Miraghsi%20-%20128.mp3\";s:7:\"radioip\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"radioport\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"buy_title_a\";s:14:\"\u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a 320\";s:10:\"buy_icon_a\";s:14:\"cloud-download\";s:10:\"buy_link_a\";s:134:\"http:\/\/dl.paradi3emusic.com\/Musics\/Aban%2094\/Persian\/Single\/Hosein%20Tohi%20And%20Sami%20Beigi%20-%20Ba%20Man%20Miraghsi%20-%20320.mp3\";s:11:\"buy_title_b\";s:14:\"\u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a 128\";s:10:\"buy_icon_b\";s:14:\"cloud-download\";s:10:\"buy_link_b\";s:134:\"http:\/\/dl.paradi3emusic.com\/Musics\/Aban%2094\/Persian\/Single\/Hosein%20Tohi%20And%20Sami%20Beigi%20-%20Ba%20Man%20Miraghsi%20-%20128.mp3\";s:11:\"buy_title_c\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"buy_icon_c\";s:14:\"cloud-download\";s:10:\"buy_link_c\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"buy_title_d\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"buy_icon_d\";s:14:\"cloud-download\";s:10:\"buy_link_d\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"buy_custom\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"lyric_title\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"lyric\";s:0:\"\";}}"
    ],
    ...
},
...
```

****EDIT*****

I want to have another custom field which contain json array of these serialized data but unserialized
also I tried this but didn't worked.

```
add_post_meta($id, 'myplaylist1', $playlist);
```

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: unless the json plugin provides filters for accessing post meta, you will need to edit the plugin directly - their are a few wordpress json plugins, which one are you using?

Comment: json api.the problem is not json i just want to create another custom field and put playlist array in that but unselialized

Comment: Again, their are a few json api plugins, please link to the correct one. Also, meta fields are stored in MySQL database (like all other wordpress data). Their is no `array` field type in MySQL, so you cant simply store an unserialized array (thats why the theme authors used serialization in the 1st place). The theme will unserialize the data when it access it - the json plugin would need to do the same. It might provide filters for this. If not you will need to edit the plugin

Comment: the plug in name is "json api" this is the link of plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/
that's right and i thank you if you do that

Comment: OK, yes that plugin has the required filters, but to write an answer i would need to see the complete json output - please either add it to your question directly, or if it is too large, create a pastebin and add the link

Comment: the json output is in my question but if you want full json page this is the link http://paradi3emusic.com/?json=get_posts&post_type=songs&count=5
you can see this in all of my posts

Comment: Ok, yes thats what i need, i'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a filter to deserialize the content before it is output by the json api plugin.

There is a filter applied by the plugin just before the json is output, documented here:

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.-Extending-JSON-API

That would be suitable for this task.

Add the following to your themes `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('json_api_encode', function($response){

    if (isset($response['posts'])) {
        foreach ($response['posts'] as $post) {
            deserialize_playlist($post);
        }
    } else if (isset($response['post'])) {
        deserialize_playlist($response['post']);
    }
    return $response;
});


function deserialize_playlist(&$post) {
    if(isset($post->custom_fields->playlist)){
        $playlists = $post->custom_fields->playlist;
        //custom fields appear to always be returned as an array
        foreach($playlists as &$playlist){
            $playlist = unserialize($playlist);
        }
        $post->custom_fields->playlist = $playlists;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress built in [maybe_unserialize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) function to unserialize a serialize data

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize